# How to remove a particular data from pointseries in amcharts v5

Tags: amcharts5

How to remove a particular data by a attribute. Amcharts have option to remove item by Index. is there any way that we can remove a particular data from series by a attribute value?

```
pointSeries.data.removeIndex(0);
```

we want something like

```
pointSeries.data.removeByAttributeValue({id:12});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `index` of the item you want to remove

```
    var index = pointSeries.data._values.findIndex(obj => obj.id == "12");
```

Then use `removeIndex`

```
    pointSeries.data.removeIndex(index);
```

Comment: Then how to remove data points between the particular range? and re-add new array between that range?